# Grammar behind “Un autre que moi”

Tags: grammaire, usage, choix-de-mot

In the song “Un autre que moi” by Fishbach the chorus goes like this:

> Eh, qu'ils nous retrouvent / 
>   On n'se rendra pas /
>   Et qu'ils avouent /
>   J'ai jamais dit ça /
>   Je découvre un autre que moi /
>   On se retrouve dans un attentat

I’m having trouble understanding what “un autre que moi” means or the grammar behind it. It seems to mean “someone other than me” but an article translates it as “another me” and in that case I don’t understand the “que” here.

In the music video Fishbach is being kidnapped but it’s revealed that she herself is the kidnapper. So the song seems to be about running away from
yourself in a way? I’m not totally sure.

Does anyone understand the title given the context? I’d love some help, thanks!

Comment: I would be tempted to say "Another *what* besides me?" and read the implied answer "Another *me* besides myself." In other words, both interpretations would be basically right: the first syntactically, the second semantically. But I may be missing something subtle.

Comment: @LukeSawczak see, what gets me is why isn’t it just “un autre moi”? why is que there? and why isn’t it “UNE autre que moi” if it’s about her? questions, questions, questions...

Comment: @jacoballens It says ***un** autre* because the article has to refer to *autre* who is male (the *il* in *Il avait l’air et la manière d’aimer*) and not to *moi* (female). If the other person had been female than it would have been ***une* autre**.

Answer (score 2):

First thing I'd like to say is that one must not try to search too deep into song lyrics.
That being said you are absolutely right in saying that *un autre que moi* et *un autre moi* mean different things. And the song does say *un autre que moi*.

- ***Un autre que moi*** refers to another physical person.
- ***Un autre moi*** refers to another abstract self, same body but different personality.

You are not linking to any translation but I've found [this one](https://www.musixmatch.com/lyrics/Fishbach/Un-autre-que-moi/translation/english):

> And they confess
> I've never said that
> I find someone other than me
> We find ourselves in an terror attack

that does not look too bad. As you see the translation is different from the one you are mentioning.

[The first translation](https://lyricstranslate.com/en/un-autre-que-moi-another-me.html) I'd hit upon went like this:

> Let them approve
> I never said that
> I've discovered another than me
> We find ourselves in a fight

both translations agree about *un autre que moi* but they are on the whole different and I think the first one I'm pointing to is much better.

Don't forget the translations on these sites are usually made by non specialists, there are often errors, and with song lyrics it's the same as with poetry, you need to do a lot of interpretation.

Concerning the particular words you are pointing to I would definitely go for "another than me" or "someone other than me" because "another me" would really change the meaning too much.

Comment: “another than me” feels weird to me. like it doesn’t seem grammatically correct or at least is a weird structure? but maybe that’s the point, i’m not sure. that’s what i immediately thought of as a translation but then i thought it sounded off

Comment: @jacoballens Concerning what sounds better in English, FL is not the place to ask. Never forget that the translations usually try to follow the rhythm of the song. And the words in French are weird too, songs often say things we do not say in real conversation.

Answer (score 1):

Plainly, it means "someone else than me" .

The lyrics are duplicated below for easy reference.

*Élancée comme une panthère dans la fumée

Le regard noir, le visage fier, le pas feutré

Ce qu'on a découvert sur terre m'a fait pleurer

Oui j’avais l’air et la manière d’aimer*

*Élancée comme une guerrière dans la mêlée

Le regard fixe, prête pour la rixe, j’ai riposté

Le goût du danger sur mes lèvres l’a fait pleurer

Il avait l’air et la manière d’aimer*

*Qu'ils nous retrouvent

On n'se rendra pas

Et qu'ils approuvent

J'ai jamais dit ça

Je découvre un autre que moi

On se retrouve dans un attentat*

*Tout allait de travers

J’sentais monter dans l'atmosphère

Un coup d’éclat, d’éclair, un coup d’tonnerre

Droite, gauche, bras d’fer, on se défend

Mais t’as vu la gueule du sentiment ?*

*Qu'ils nous retrouvent

On n'se rendra pas

Et qu'ils approuvent

J'ai jamais dit ça

Je découvre un autre que moi

On se retrouve un autre attentat*

There is no evidence to infer wheter "un autre que moi" means "someone other than me" or "another me", "another myself". There are two main protagonists in the situation referred to, a woman, who is the narrator (first person point of view), this being elicited from the gender agreement (élancé**e**) and a man, this last fact being elicited from the masculine pronoun "il". In such a context of vague references I'm inclined to opt for the most straightforward interpretation: there is no question of another self but only of someone else (**il**).
There is an undubitable parallel: she cries, shows love in one way, he cries too and shows love in the same way, but from that to infer a "double value" for "un autre que moi" is doubly contrived, too complicated, so much so as it is just as legitimate if not more to expect "un autre moi" (another one such as me"), therefore someone different yet not unlike myself. We are not even sure that the masculine protagonist is on her side; the speculation of finding him on the other side is open.   I do not personally understand the aim in making in this and countless other lyrics, the meaning so unaccessible to the listener, so uncertain; the impact  is obviously enormously diminished by this intended vagueness as the audience is bound to retain nothing specific from such a piece of literature, even after much pondering over of the few possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

This is called "licence poétique" where the writer/poet bends grammar to make it fit the rhythm of the song. Without the "que" you are missing a beat in the line when sung. Try singing it without the que and something is missing. The same happens with poetry.
It also helps with the sense of schizophrenia that is inherent to the song.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).